# Android Studio get pixel array from image resource

Tags: image, android-studio, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I am trying to get a pixel array(or Bitmap) from a resource and then parse the pixels of the bitmap like this: `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResourcea(), R.drawable.image1);`

But since my image is large 5000x3000 resolution this method throws OOM exception. Actually I took this picture from my custom app and I managed to cast the byte array from the `hardware.Camera.takePicture()` method to a bitmap and had no problem with memory when I parsed the image.

So my question is how can I parse my large image when it is in the resources without throwing OutOfMemory exception?

Thanks!

Comment: visit this it may help you. https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks. I already looked at the post. I don't want to scale down the bitmap because I will loose pixels. And I don't actually need to DISPLAY the bitmap, I just need to parse the pixels. Their solution is connected with scaling down the bitmap, which I do not want.